# Headphone not working? Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: headphones

Okay, so I just installed Ubuntu alongside windows 7 and my headphones dont seem to be working, when I plug in my headphones the sound continues to come out of the speakers built into my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Fine, just try these steps..

There is a sound icon on the top-right bar. Click on it -> Sound Settings' -> 'Hardware' Tab -> 'Settings for the selected device: Profile: and chose some different options from the selection list. There is a button 'Test Speakers', you can test your sound when ever you chose different options. On the same window go to 'Output' tab and change other options from the list below.

you can also go to sound setting from 'All Settings' -> 'Sound'. Right click on desktop and chose 'Change Desktop Background' -> 'All Setting' tab -> 'Sound'.

Reply if something goes wrong..